# Adding App compact v7 library gives error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have been using android support library v13 till now which was working fine. Now I need to add custom tool bar for which I am adding app compact library to my project. But when I am adding `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'` to my gradle file, its giving my 128 error for duplicate or missing variable in values folder. Not sure how to remove it.

Following is the dependencies for my library project where I am adding app compact library

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile files('libs/androidannotations-api-2.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec.jar')
    compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

Following are the dependencies in my project

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':projFramework')
    compile files('lib/PatchServices.jar')
    compile files('lib/analyticsmonitor.jar')
    compile files('lib/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile files('lib/bugsense-3.6.1.jar')
    compile files('lib/robospice-1.2.0.jar')
}
```

***121*** errors were shown .

**Update**

Changing the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 23, only thing is it reduced the number of errors. But still I am getting the error.

```
C:\UserData\AndroidStudioWorkspace\Proj\projFramework\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values\values.xml
Error:(2) Attribute "buttonStyle" has already been defined
Error:Execution failed for task ':projFramework:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\UserData\Android\android-sdk-windows-update\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.611 secs
```

Comment: what's your version of buildtools ??

Comment: @Fakher  
compileSdkVersion 23    ||    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"  ||  minSdkVersion 14  ||    targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: have you tried with this for libs `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Comment: Nope but its not making any difference

Comment: Do you have a custom <attr/> ?

Comment: Yup, it seems that was the problem. In my library project I am using same attr. I dont know for sure whether renaming will be helpful or not, but that the solution. Thanks @Neil